# What's different between query by $elemMatch and json query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

as the title I query mongodb by $elemMatch operator and by json query style but they have the same result. 
My question: what's different between them?
example:
I have mongodb table 3 records:

```
[{
  "name": "test1",
  "address": [
  {"city": ["c1","c2"]},
  {"district": ["d1","d2"]}
  ]
},
{
  "name": "test2",
  "address": [
  {"city": ["c2","c3"]},
  {"district": ["d2","d3"]}
  ]
},
{
  "name": "test3",
  "address": [
  {"city": ["c2","c4"]},
  {"district": ["d2","d4"]}
  ]
}]
```

I do query as below:

> filter 1. {"address.city":{$elemMatch:{$eq:"c2"}}} 
>  filter 2.
> {"address.city":"c2"}
>  filter 1, filter 2: show the same records
> (3 records)

===========

> filter 3. {"address.city":{$elemMatch:{$eq:"c1"}}}
>  filter 4.
> {"address.city":"c1"}
>  filter 3, filter 4: show the same record (1
> record: test1)

if they are the same, filter2, filter4 are better becase of it's simpler ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: There isn't any difference in your examples, as [explained in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition)